# Deploy to container Plugin (1.13) doesn't give manager username & password under Post Build Actions

Tags: jenkins

I'm not able to deploy war files on Tomcat 7 via Jenkins. I've installed the Deploy to container Plugin (1.13) in Jenkins.
However, when I created a job to deploy war file, on selecting Tomcat 7.x as the container through Post Build Action step, I'm not getting the manager username & password fields. I'm just getting the Jenkins Credentials Provider option which doesn't work for container manager login.

screenshot of the Post Build Action section for my Jenkins job.

[image: Jenkins_Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This change in the user interface is done to implements a security fix. You can get more details here 
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/JENKINS/issues/JENKINS-52504?filter=allopenissues

You can now use the Credentials plugin. Use the new interface through the credentials plugin. There is an "Add Credentials" button next to it (as shown in your image) to do that, and it seems like you have added credentials.